# .htaccess 301 redirect for https and www

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect

I'm struggeling with the apache rewrite engine and need help to transform these address-variations:

```
http://www.site.de/index.php
www.site.de/index.php
http://site.de/index.php
site.de/index.php
```

to this form with `www` and `https`:

```
https://www.site.de/index.php
```

How would the statement look like and how does it work?

Currently it works from non-`www` to `www`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^site.de [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://www.site.de/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

But it ignores the `https`.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution:

There must be a second rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```